# Swift -> my prototype cell (UITableViewCell) doesn't show in my UIViewController with a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, prototype, cell

My storyboard looks like this

[image: StoryBoard]

[image]

and my code is the following

UIViewController

class DownLoadSoundsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
// MARK: View Controller Properties
let viewName = "DownLoadSoundsViewController"
@IBOutlet weak var visualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!
@IBOutlet weak var dismissButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var downloadTableView: UITableView!

// MARK: Properties
var soundPacks = [SoundPack?]()  // structure for downloadable sounds

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    downloadTableView.dataSource = self
    downloadTableView.delegate = self
    downloadTableView.register(DownLoadTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfSoundPacks
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let method = "tableView.cellForRowAt"

    //if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "downloadTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DownLoadTableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    if soundPacks[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]?.price == 0 {
        cell.soundPackPriceUILabel.text = "FREE"
    } else {
        cell.soundPackPriceUILabel.text = String(format: "%.2", (soundPacks[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]?.price)!)
    }

    //cell.textLabel?.text = soundPacks[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]?.soundPackTitle
    cell.soundPackTitleUILabel.text = soundPacks[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]?.soundPackTitle
    cell.soundPackAuthorUILabel.text = soundPacks[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]?.author
    cell.soundPackShortDescription.text = soundPacks[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]?.shortDescription

    cell.soundPackImage.image = UIImage(named: "Placeholder Icon")
    DDLogDebug("\(viewName).\(method): table section \((indexPath as NSIndexPath).section) row \((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row))")

    return cell
    //}
}
```

UItableViewCell

class DownLoadTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var soundPackImage: UIImageView!    
@IBOutlet weak var soundPackTitleUILabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var soundPackAuthorUILabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var soundPackShortDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var soundPackPriceUILabel: UILabel!

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

But I get the following;

[image: Result - UGH!]

I am sure I am doing something small incorrectly, but as of yet can't figure it out.  Looked through many examples included my own code where I have gotten this working before.

Not a single one of my settings for the tableview are getting invoked except the number of cells.  But everything in;

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{...}

is not working.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you print `numberOfSoundPacks.count`? I think it's an empty array.

Comment: Yes.  It's 3.  but that might be it.  It's set after a return call from firebase.  So possible that it's not set in time.  will try and let you know.

Comment: okay! Did you reload the tableView after getting data from Firebase? `downloadTableView.reloadData()`

Comment: You're awesome.  That was it.  needed to add                 self.downloadTableView.reloadData()
Now, works like a charm.  duh.  been staring at this code too long.

Comment: yess! I added a answer, please accept it to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reload the tableView after getting data from Firebase

```
self.saveMixesTableView.reloadData()
```